# Cross Thread invoke (c#, WaveEngine)

Tags: c#, multithreading, grpc

I'm looking for a way to **invoke a function on a different thread**.

We are working with a server(gRPC) which sends out data when it receives it, a task is running at the client and will proceed the loop once it receives new data(`stream.MoveNext()`).

Once it receives new data it will invoke a function, although this is done within a different thread

NOTE: I'm not getting the `Cross-Thread Exception`, this is because its disabled during build and testing on developer machine is impossible.

```
public static async Task ButtonStream()
{

    var rpc = buttonClient.buttonPressed(new ButtonsSubscription());
    try
    {
        using (rpc)
        {
            var stream = rpc.ResponseStream;
            while (await stream.MoveNext())
            {
                if (stream.Current.Id >= persistantDic.Count)
                {
                    int a = stream.Current.Id;
                    int b = persistantDic.Count;

                    //Console.WriteLine("{0} >= {1}", a,b);
                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
                }
                else
                {
                    buttonPressed = stream.Current.Id;
                    gRPCEvents.ButtonUpdates?.Invoke ();
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoked from thread: "+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (RpcException e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`ButtonUpdates?.Invoke` runs a function within main(threadID 1), When i press F1(Testing purpose only) i see that its running the function on Thread 1, but when it gets invoked its running function on Thread 4 (or 9, changes sometimes).

**EDIT**

The function on main thread is subscribed to the delegate invoked, which will be invoked by a task on thread 4

Comment: So what is your problem/question?

Comment: what a proper way would be to invoke these functions across different threads

Comment: You *don't* need Invoke when you use `async`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP wants post it for some update function to be called on separate thread, which I assume has some processing logic

Comment: @MrinalKamboj `runs a function within main(threadID 1)` that's the UI thread. If `ButtonStream` is called by the UI thread, `Invoke` isn't necessary.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj let me clarify that, on main thread there is a function subscribed to that delegate.

Comment: @Maxdg, can you please comment on my answer what is unclear. You cannot update control on any other thread than main thread. 
Async doesn't need a separate thread, and its an ideal way to control the process in background

Comment: @MrinalKamboj just added own answer, spoke with a dev from WaveEngine and he supplied me with 3 easy lines which did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved,

WaveEngine was so kind to provide me with an easy solution to hook in to their main thread

```
WaveServices.Dispatcher.RunOnWaveThread(() =>
{
    //Any code here for execution
});
```

Comment: What execution do you undertake in the Wave thread, does it allow Ui control update

Comment: @MrinalKamboj On the wavethread i change the textures and animate objects around.